# UIButton not receiving clicks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

So this is the code i have:

```
    UIButton *svObjectButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    svObjectButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

    [svObjectButton addTarget:self action:@selector(svObjectTouchUpInside) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];       
    [svView addSubview:svObjectButton];

    UIButton *removeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    removeButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
    [removeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(removeButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [svObjectButton addSubview:removeButton];
    [svObjectButton bringSubviewToFront:removeButton];
```

But for some reason all touches on removeButton go straight through to svObjectButton.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are adding one small button on another big button. To achieve this, you can add
one UIView (for example buttonView) with big button frame size on `svView`. After that you can add both buttons on `buttonView` (`UIview`). You have to avoid:

```
[svObjectButton addSubview:removeButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does the removeButton have to be a subview of the svObjectButton?

I think the problem lies in a UIButton being subview of a UIButton. Try adding the removeButton to svView instead.